# Exposed Post date filter on views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

When you expose a filter date on views you get something similar to the following:

[image: screenshot #1]

When you expose the post date you get:

[image: screenshot #2]

The former is a lot more useful. Is there a way you can get the post date to look the same?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure therefore add a date: filter not a node: post date.

On the date filter configuration form you can select the node: post date field and that's all you need.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

To those looking to integrate this filter in a `hook_views_data()` definition in your own module (say, if you're trying to expose your own custom table to Views 2.x or 3.x), you need to have the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) installed, and then you can add in the following in your field definition:

```
'filter' => array(
    'handler' => 'date_views_filter_handler_simple', // Requires date.module.
),
```

The full field definition for a created date, updated date, etc. would be something like the following:

```
'field_created' => array(
  'title' => t('My Created Date'),
  'help' => t('When an item was created.'),
  'field' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
    'click sortable' => TRUE,
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'handler' => 'date_views_filter_handler_simple', // Requires date.module.
  ),
),
```