# Views Exposed Filter with Specific Values

Tags: views

I have a view that requires an exposed filter of years starting at 1980 and incrementing every 4 years (1980, 1984, 1988, etc) all the way to the last year of that meets this criteria, i.e. 2012.  Is there a way to do this?  So far I have only been able to create a select element with every year from 1980 to today.  I've also tried using a global php field but cannot figure out how to expose that to the end user.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29983/views-exposed-filter-date-year